# Windows batch file to delete folders/subfolders that contain spaces

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below to delete folders 10 days old:

```
FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

BUT if the @path variable contains spaces it won't delete that folder.

I tried "@path" but nothing. Any help regarding this.
Thanks,

Comment: It works for me on Vista - @path already is quoted, so you shouldn't add your own. Are you sure the directory is at least 10 days old?

Comment: There were some new files inside the directory, but the directory itself was like months old. I tried on some other directory with spaces and strangely it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating or modifying files within a folder does not update the folder timestamp. Creating or deleting a child *folder* within the parent folder *will* update the parent folder timestamp.

Your folder with spaces probably was not deleted because a child folder was manipulated in some way within the last 10 days. The failure probably has nothing to do with spaces in the name. Try a `DIR` command from the parent of the folder and look at the date for the folder.